# Monitor folders using unix bash

Tags: bash, unix

I need a shell script that will monitor all the folders given in the command 
and will notify the user if a certain file will be created inside them (the name of 
the file will be read from keyboard).

I am allowed to use simple commands, so not inotify...
this is what i managed to do so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo "Please enter a file you want to monitor: "
    read file_monitor
    #this is an infinite while
    while [ 1 ] ; do 
        #using test -e to search for the file
        test -e $file_monitor && echo "The file has been created!"
        sleep 5
    done
```

I have to find a way to stop the while when the file has been created, and also to search for the file in the folders given in the command line. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Just `exit` from the script when your file is found.

Comment: Can you use `[[`? If so then just test in the while condition: `while [[ ! -f $file_monitor ]]; do `

Comment: please add the missing `"`, and whitespace for `while`. Please *test* your code before posting.

Comment: i have tested my code, but i didn't copy paste it

Answer (score 0):

To exit the loop, use `break`:

```
test -e $file_monitor && echo "The file has been created!" && break
```

I would prefer to `break` first, and `echo` after the loop, or as @mkemp6 suggested, directly use the test as the condition for the loop.

To check the folders, simply loop through them, and check the file in each one.

```
break [n]
       Exit from within a for, while, until, or select loop.  If n  is  specified,  break  n
       levels.   n  must  be  ≥  1.  If n is greater than the number of enclosing loops, all
       enclosing loops are exited.
```

Comment: thanks, that solves the break problem :) now i need to figure out how to search in certain folders

Answer (score 0):

```
while ! test -e "$file_monitor"; do sleep 5; done
```

But you are much better off using something like inotify to monitor the appropriate directories.

Comment: i can't use inotify because this is for a school assignment, and now my problem is how to search in folders given as arguments in the command line. this code will only work for the current directory

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
arr=$@

for i in $arr; do
    if [ ! -d $i ]
      then echo "The parameter $i is no a directory!"
          exit 1
    fi
done

echo -n "Please give file you want to monitor: "
read file_monitor

a=1

while [ $a -eq 1 ]; do
    for i in $arr; do
        cd $i
        test -e $file_monitor && echo "The file has been created" && a=$((a+1))
        cd ..
    done
done
```

So this is what I have managed to do.